# Why is some package not installable?

Tags: r, installation, package

I was trying to install "R2wd" package. I checked that my R and R studio is up to date which I believe is 3.2.1 for R. However I am having trouble installing the package. What do I have to check?
I am on Mac, like 7 years old iMac and newest version of mac OS.
In terms of R2wd,

Depends R (>= 2.10.0)

> install.packages("R2wd")
>   Warning in install.packages :
>     package 'R2wd' is not available (for R version 3.2.1)

Comment: Let's start with the obvious.  Are you on Windows? Also, you can read about the requirements for R2wd [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2wd/index.html)

Comment: Sorry. I edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2wd/index.html under "System Requirements".  You must have Windows to install the R2wd package.

[image]

Comment: No problem, happens to everyone :)